# android widget for remote org agenda

Tags: android, project-management, ssh, server, widget

I have an [org file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Org-mode) on a remote server, which I use as a task list and agenda. I'm all about making organisation stuff as seamless as possible, so I'm looking for a widget for my android homescreen which shows my incoming deadlines and agenda, updating automatically. I've tried looking for a SSH widget which keeps an emacs window open, but that doesn't exist, and wouldn't auto-update.

I have root access to the server, could write some code if it's not too much trouble (coding on android is too much trouble), and understand how cron works.

How might I solve this?

Comment: Why not go for an established solution, like using a calendar server (e.g. Baïkal or ownCloud) instead of your file, and have that synchronized with your Android device? Then you could use any of the available [Calendar Widgets](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_widgets). Note that this site is about *recommending software* – not giving howtos, tutorials or consulting on "best approaches" ;)

Comment: Because org mode allows exactly the type of structure I need, and allows me to program features myself when they're lacking.
I understand this is about software, not about programming or system management, but my problem is a little bit in the middle
If I were to ask this on superuser, the response would be "go to a site about software recommendations" ;)

Comment: What is "org file" for you?

Comment: I've just added the link to Wikipedia's *Org-mode* page. Following its links, there seem to be "plugins" to export to other formats, e.g. [SuperMemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperMemo). This format again is used by flashcard software such as [Anki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anki_%28software%29). Circle end point: Maybe [AnkiDroid](https://github.com/ankidroid/Anki-Android) can deal with that somehow?